# Array tool not working properly - Blender 3.4

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a tyre model in blender, following a tutorial video exactly. I'm not sure what causes my version of blender to do this (first image) and not that (second image). My settings are exactly what it says on the video, except I'm on a different version.
Tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a90cYLEbpi4 27:30

[image: Red arrow points to where my model is]

[image]

[image: Settings in the tutorial]

[image: Settings in my blender]

Comment: Firstly add an image showing Blender's complete window which you can do via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender, and secondly we have no idea what tutorial you're trying to follow so please add a link to it at the postion where you're having problems. (You can do that, at least under Windows, by pausing your video then right-clicking on it and selecting "Copy video URL at current time".)

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit questions on this I just signed up but this is the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a90cYLEbpi4

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @GUPPYFISH1030 There should be an Edit button just below your question. What timestamp in the video does Darrin detail how to array the tire tread? As moonboots says, we'll problably need to see your file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.